# WPF Button partly not working after clicked few times fast

Tags: c#, wpf, button, data-binding, bing-maps

I am having a button that when I click it should change the mode of bing map and change the image on the button:

```
<Button x:Name="ModeButton" Grid.Column="0" Background="#00000000" BorderThickness="0" Click="ChangeMapMode" MouseDoubleClick="ChangeMapMode">
    <Image Source="{Binding MapModePicName}" Width="30" Height="30" />
</Button>
```

the map element:

```
<m:Map Mode="{Binding MapMode}/>"
```

the event of clicking:

```
        private void ChangeMapMode(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MapMode is RoadMode)
            {
                MapMode = new AerialMode();
            }
            else
                MapMode = new RoadMode();
        }
```

the properties:

```
        public MapMode MapMode
        {
            get
            {
                return mode;
            }
            set
            {
                mode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MapMode));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MapModePicName));
            }
        }
        public string MapModePicName
        {
            get
            {
                return MapMode is RoadMode ? "/Images/RoadsMap.png" : "/Images/AerialMap.png";
            }
        }
```

The mode of the map is binding to MapMode.
when I click the button everything works, but when I click it twice or more, fast it is acting weird. After that the mode of the map is not changing anymore when I click, but the image on the button is still changing as it should. This is also very weird because the image on the button is according to the property binding to the mode.
I tried to handle the event of double click, and it worked for the case of double click, but still failed on 3 or more fast clicks.
I also tried to disable the button while I handle the event to check if it is because the button is clicked before the event handling is over, but it still didn't work.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the mode of the map is not changing anymore"? Per your description, the code you show us here works fine. Which "map" are you referring to?

Comment: I said I am using the bing maps. I edited and added the code of the map.

Comment: My guess, not having used that map control before, would be that the mode switch is something that takes some time, and perhaps it is still switching modes the next time you click in quick succession.   I have used similar mapping controls where that was the case.

Comment: Give the `Map` a name (x:Name), put a breakpoint in `ChangeMapMode` and see if the `Map.Mode` property is actually changing.